# Codename One open side menu programatically

Tags: java, codenameone

I'm trying to make the side menu open on my app from code.
My form uses the toolbar to populate the side menu with more complicated components.
I've used this to close the menu:

```
SideMenuBar.closeCurrentMenu();
```

but I can't find the equivalent open function.
I attempted this:

```
        if(f.getToolbar() !=null){
            MenuBar mb = f.getToolbar().getMenuBar();
            if(mb!=null){
                mb.showMenu();
            }    
        }
```

but It is throwing a null pointer because it can't find any commands (Toolbar.java line 490)

stack trace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.util.ArrayList.<init>(ArrayList.java:177)
at com.codename1.ui.list.DefaultListModel.<init>(DefaultListModel.java:65)
at com.codename1.ui.List.<init>(List.java:275)
at com.codename1.ui.Toolbar.createOverflowCommandList(Toolbar.java:490)
at com.codename1.ui.Toolbar$ToolbarSideMenu.createCommandComponent(Toolbar.java:799)
at com.codename1.ui.MenuBar.showMenu(MenuBar.java:692)
at com.startex.coffee.managers.forms.MyCardsController.lambda$setupButtonActions$5(MyCardsController.java:217)
at com.codename1.ui.util.EventDispatcher.fireActionSync(EventDispatcher.java:455)
at com.codename1.ui.util.EventDispatcher.fireActionEvent(EventDispatcher.java:358)
at com.codename1.ui.Button.fireActionEvent(Button.java:411)
at com.codename1.ui.Button.released(Button.java:442)
at com.codename1.ui.Button.pointerReleased(Button.java:530)
at com.codename1.ui.Form.pointerReleased(Form.java:2578)
at com.codename1.ui.Form.pointerReleased(Form.java:2514)
at com.codename1.ui.Component.pointerReleased(Component.java:3119)
at com.codename1.ui.Display.handleEvent(Display.java:2017)
at com.codename1.ui.Display.edtLoopImpl(Display.java:1065)
at com.codename1.ui.Display.mainEDTLoop(Display.java:994)
at com.codename1.ui.RunnableWrapper.run(RunnableWrapper.java:120)
at com.codename1.impl.CodenameOneThread.run(CodenameOneThread.java:176)
```

Comment: Can you post the stack of the `NullPointerException`? The line numbers are no longer up to date with the current trunk so I have no idea what failed although there is no requirement to add anything to the overflow menu...

Comment: The accepted answer below worked for me, but I've added the stack trace in the event that it can help you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The SideMenuBar has the non-static method [openMenu(String direction)](http://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/ui/SideMenuBar.html#openMenu-java.lang.String-). To open a normal  SideMenuBar you can proceed like this:

```
SideMenuBar smb = (SideMenuBar) Display.getInstance().getCurrent().getMenuBar();
smb.openMenu(null);
```

I suppose in your case f is the Form and since you are using the ToolBar you have to call getMenuBar() on getToolbar() and then cast it to a SideMenuBar as folowing:

```
((SideMenuBar)f.getToolbar().getMenuBar()).openMenu(null);
```

Please note that the openMenu() method has a direction parameter, which I'm not entirely sure what it does. For me it works with null. I think it is needed if you don't have the menu on the left side, for that [this link](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/on-the-side-up-on-top.html) might help.

Comment: Yeah this worked for me. For left (default) side menus it would have worked with the null. In my case the menu is on the right so I had to use:
`((SideMenuBar)f.getToolbar().getMenuBar()).openMenu(COMMAND_PLACEMENT_VALUE_RIGHT);` where COMMAND_PLACEMENT_VALUE_RIGHT is from the SideMenuBar class. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

1. The nullpointer is due to empty overflow commands so add some commands to overflowmenu and the null pointer is solved and it shows overflowmenu

   Toolbar toolbar = new Toolbar();
   f.setToolbar(toolbar);
   toolbar.addCommandToOverflowMenu(new Command("hi hi "));
2. To show sidemenu add the following code

   ```
    SideMenuBar sideMenuBar= (SideMenuBar)Display.getInstance().getCurrent().getMenuBar();
    sideMenuBar.openMenu(null);
   ```

Comment: Actaully my side menu already has commands, the issue was this command would only open the left side menu and mine is on the right